# RPG project, maybe make a method to set the class?

Tags: java

So in my code, i have print statements with choices of different classes, and the user then types in the number corresponding with whatever class they want to be. I have Classes for each class i have, like Knight, Cyborg, Bandit, and JohnCena, each is a different Class with different stats in those Classes. What I was trying to do was to have the user automatically start off as a Knight(Galactic Marine) and then somehow change that data type to whatever specific class that the user chooses. I have a variable called user and its declared as type Knight, and i was trying to change the type to the specific class that the user chooses, but idk how to do that...

Here is a link to my code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVRJA.jpg

Comment: Is there any reason to automatically start as a knight? You may also want to look into an abstract CharacterType class along with either the Factory or Builder design patterns

Comment: No there is no reason for me to start as a knight I just dont know the easiest way to do this...I should have mentioned that I am very new to Java and am taking a beginner Java class, so most of the stuff we are using is pretty basic. @cricket_007

Comment: How will they play as JohnCena if they can't see him?

Answer (score 0):

Using a switch case might be helpful in this case.

```
Scanner chooseclass=new Scanner(System.in);
int classchoice=chooseclass.nextInt();
switch(classchoice)
{
     case 1:
     //your code to convert the class to Bandit
     break;
     case 2:
     //your code to convert the class to Galactic Marine
     break;
     case 3:
     //your code to convert the class to Cyborg
     break;
     case 4:
     //your code to convert the class to John Cena
     break;
     default:
     System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice"):
}
```

Comment: btw what will happen if the user decides not to continue?

Comment: lol ok . That's a pretty good idea though I couldn't even think of creating an rpg using BlueJ.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have only one class which defines job classes.

Stats are field member variables of character class.

```
public class Job {
    public String jobName;
    public int strength;
    public int speed;
    ...
}
```

Then, for the user choice, stats values are varied.

For example:

```
knight -> jobName: knight; strength: 12; speed:  5; etc...
bandit -> jobName: bandit; strength:  7; speed: 11; etc...
```

Code is like:

```
int classChoice = chooseclass.nextInt();

Job job = new Job();

switch (classChoice) {
case 0:
    job.jobName = "knight";
    job.strength = 12;
    job.speed = 5;
    ...
    break;
case 1:
    job.jobName = "bandit";
    job.strength = 7;
    job.speed = 11;
    ...
    break;
...
}
```

When attack, for example:

```
public void attack() {
    switch (jobName) {
    case "knight":
        System.out.println("You slash it with sword.");
        break;
    case "bandit":
        System.out.println("You throw a dagger.");
        break;
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont think i understand what you are saying, because at the top of my code, before i created multiple classes, i defined the variable user as type Knight, and then used that variable later on in my code to call certain methods from the Knight class, so how can i do that? im being very vague im sorry but the more I think about it the more I confuse myself XD

Comment: You can check jobName and deside to call certain methods or not. I know you have defined some classes for all jobs, but if I were you, I would do with just one class definition.

Comment: That makes sense but how to switches work, like how would I trigger a switch to choose the class when the user chooses?

Comment: Thanks man that helps a lot! Makes my code a whole lot easier

Comment: @NoahRobinson You are welcome. I like such project. Cheers!